# Next JS pages/api; having trouble calling influxdb client from api

Tags: next.js, rxjs, influxdb

I have written a handler function inside my nextjs page/api folder;

```
handler(req, res) {}
```

Am using @influxdata/influxDb-client as mentioned in the documentation. Am using

```
from(queryAPI.rows(query).pipe(....).subscribe(next(value)=> {results.push(value}, complete(console.log(results); res.status(200).json(results)}
```

Am getting all the query value, once the observable is completed. it works most of the time.

Am pushing the intermediate results in the next part of the subscriber and trying to send the results back to client in the complete part of the subscriber. I want the request handler to wait till i get all my values from influx DB query in the complete part of the subscriber and can send the value back to client..

But the issue "Handler function will not Wait till the observable is completed". Handler function returns, before the observer gets completed. Am getting error: **API resolved without sending a response**...

I get all the values only when the observer is completed.
I don't know how to handle the scenario.

How can I make the handler function wait until the observable is completed?

Comment: Hey Vijay, it's really hard to understand what you want here.  The code you've posted doesn't make much sense.  Maybe provide a more complete example?

Comment: @DanielGimenez I am running the following query inside a request handler of a next js application (Pages/API)

from(queryAPI.rows(query).
subscribe(
       next(value)=> {results.push(value}, 
       error(error)=>{res.status(400).json({err: error)}}
        complete(console.log(results); res.status(200).json(results);

Full data will be received only when the above observable gets completed. If you observe, am pushing the value in the next part of the subscriber and trying to send the final results in the completed part of the subscriber.

Comment: But before that request handler returns the value to the client. Am not able to send the data to the client. I want the observable to be  completed in this case and send the data from the request handler

Comment: am getting error: API resolved without sending a response

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for the same

I used new Promise() **with await**, added my observable inside this promise and ***resolved the promise on Complete of the subscribe***.

Code will look like the following :

```
  export async function handler (req, res) {
    const results=[];
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      from((queryAPIs.rows(query))
      .pipe(map(({values, tableMeta}) => tableMeta.toObject(values)))
      .subscribe(
       {
         next(object) => {results.push(object)}
         complete() => { resolve (results) }
         error(err) => { reject (err) }
        });
        res.status(200).send(results);

}
}
```